# Meaning of 「まだ跡継ぎとしては幼い弟———私を護ってくれる姉上のことだ」

Tags: manga, reading-comprehension

Reading a manga and it says まだ跡継ぎとしては幼い弟———私を護ってくれる姉上のことだ
Here's the image. It's the first page of the manga and introducing the story. I'm reading it but its meaning is not exactly clear, and machine translators seem to be having a brainfart.

[image]

Am I correct in reading the meaning of the sentence as meaning: This is the story of my older sister... who still treats me like her young successor. ?

Comment: Have you looked up the word? It even has 「まも」 in the ruby, so you wouldn't even have to guess the reading.

Comment: "I'm reading it but its meaning is not exactly clear" - where exactly are you confused? What parts do you understand, and where does e.g. the grammar fall apart for you?

Comment: My bad on misreading it. I would delete the post in light of this blunder (as it probably derails the question in the first place since my misunderstanding was premised on an incorrect reading) but I'm not allowed to. 

@KarlKnechtel I interpret the clause before the dash to be "A young brother as an heir" and after the dash to be "[it's] about aneue who protects me" but I don't understand the interaction between them - why it's supposed to mean what it means overall. 
It appears to me(now) to be "It's about my older sister who protects me - [who is] still a younger brother as an heir."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 持ってくれる is closer in meaning to "To be in charge of" or "To take care of" in this context.

I also feel that he isn't "her successor" but "a successor" since として means something close to "As a" so it's "As an heir...", that however doesn't really translate well into English so I would translate it into "... despite being the heir (to something important)".

That is to say that the sentence should be translated as:

> "This is about (the story of) my older sister coddling (pampering\taking care of) me like I'm still her baby brother despite being the heir"

And I might consider replacing "my older sister coddling" with "...**how** my older sister coddles me..." as it better conveys the meaning but isn't as literal.

**Edit**: Just noticed that the image says "護って..." and not ”持って" so it's actually about how she acts as his bodyguard and treating him like her baby brother despite him being the heir (and at least in his opinion - not a baby anymore). Thus, I'd revise my translation to:

> "This is about (the story of) my older sister guarding me like I'm still her baby brother (which I believe I'm not) despite being the heir"

Hope this helps!

Comment: `treating him like her baby brother despite him being the heir (and at least in his opinion - not a baby anymore` <-- 「自分は、後継ぎとしてはまだ幼な過ぎるので、姉が守ってくれている」、ってことです。"It's about my older sister, who guards her little brother (=me), who is too young to be a successor" って意味です。姉が自分を子ども扱いしているとか、自分が自分を幼いと思っていないとかいうことではないです。

Comment: @Chocolate  Are you rebutting the answer? I'm not sure what you're saying

Comment: @フィラシマカロト Actually, yes, I am saying the following part of the interpretation/translation in this answer is not correct: `treating him like her baby brother despite him being the heir (and at least in his opinion - not a baby anymore`, `like I'm still her baby brother (which I believe I'm not)`

Comment: and you would say a more accurate translation is, " "It's about my older sister, who guards her little brother (=me), who is too young to be a successor " ?

Comment: Upon reading @Chocolate comment I have to agree with him.

Comment: @フィラシマカロト The sentence is basically saying "It's about my older sister. She's guarding/protecting me, since I'm too young as a successor". A literal translation would be "It's about my older sister, who guards me -- her younger brother, who is too young as a successor."